# Select User by Profile name in Laravel way

Tags: laravel, eloquent, permissions

I have models User and Profile with hasOne relationship as following:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I want to select all users by full_name attribute of Profile in Laravel way. I have tried to this code but it return all the users in user table.

```
User::with(['profile' => function ($q) use ($request) {
    $q->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('name') . '%');
}]);
```

Any idea? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `whereHas` method like:

```
User::whereHas('profile', function($q) use($request) {
    $q->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->input('name') . '%');
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Now I understand more about with and where.

Comment: Glad i could help

Comment: If this answer can solve your problem, then mark it as accepted